# lie group homomorphism and compactness

Tags: differential-geometry

Let
$f\colon M\rightarrow N$ be a surjective homomorphism of lie groups. Assume the follwoing:

- f has discrete kernel $ker(f)=\{e,-e\}$
- a path from $e$ to $-e$ exisits
- $N$ is connected

**Claim**: $M$ is connected.

Would like some hints on how to prove that. It's hard for me to come up with something helpful here, since my knowledge in lie groups is not as good.

edit: f is surjective

Comment: You may try to show that $f$ is a covering.

Comment: more explicitly, discrete kernel implies it's a covering, and then use the covering homotopy property.

Comment: Okay, I was able to show that f is a covering and I understand the rest. Thanks.

Comment: I want to add another question: I used the following fact: "given any discrete normal subgroup of a Lie group the quotient group is a Lie group and the quotient map is a covering homomorphism". Can you give me a source (book prefered) for that statement, where a proof is also shown?